# Unable to use f:metadata f:viewAction from inside components

Tags: jsf, metadata, facelets, templating, viewaction

In the following page i am not able to load `automobileLists` since the method to populate it is outside the component in a `f:metadata`. I have a nullPointerException error.
Partial code :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>title</title>
</h:head>
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{primeAutomobileController.populateAutomobileFieldList}"/>
</f:metadata>

<ui:composition template="layout/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">.....................
```

The only way for me to load it is to scope the `primeAutomobileController` to session instead of the original request, and call the method from a preceding page through a button, i would like it to load at the starting of the page instead withouth calling it previously. The method in question :

```
public void populateAutomobileFieldList(){
    List<String> automobileFieldSource = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> automobileFieldTarget = new ArrayList<>();
    automobileFieldSource.add("Make");
    automobileFieldSource.add("Model");
    automobileFieldSource.add("Year");
    automobileFieldSource.add("Description");
    setAutomobileList(new DualListModel<>
        (automobileFieldSource, automobileFieldTarget));
}
```

Partial *index.xhtml* page where `f:metadata` gets loaded

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>title</title>
</h:head>
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{primeAutomobileController.loadAutomobiles}"/>
    <f:viewAction action="#{primeAutomobileController.populateAutomobileFieldList}"/>
</f:metadata>

<ui:composition template="layout/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content"> ......................
```

Here both methods in `f:metadata` get properly loaded, like it's shown in an example in a video tutorial i'm following, but when it's the same exact code in a differe xhtml it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of [metadata tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/metadata.html) shows how it must be done when using templating (how the template must look like and how to use it in the template client) :

> The implementation must allow templating for this element **according to
>   the following pattern**.
>
> template client XHTML view, view01.xhtml
>
> ```
> <ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
>     <ui:define name="metadata">
>       <f:metadata>
>         <f:viewParam name="id"/>
>       </f:metadata>
>     </ui:define>
>     <ui:define name="content">
>         <h1>The big news stories of the day</h1>
>     </ui:define>
> </ui:composition>
> ```
>
> Note line 4. The page author must ensure that the `<f:metadata>` element
>   does not appear on a template or included page. It must reside on the
>   root page that corresponds to the viewId.
>
> The template page, template.xhtml
>
> ```
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
>       xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>       xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
>       xml:lang="en" lang="en">
>
> <body>
> <f:view>
>
>         <ui:insert name="metadata"/>
>
>     <div id="container">
>         <ui:insert name="content"/>
>     </div>
> </f:view>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> The page author is not required to use templating, **but if they do, it
>   must be done as shown above**

Comment: I've tried following the example but it still doesn't load to me, i added in the post my `index.xhtml` page, where the exact same code gets loaded.

Comment: @mrsir: did you actually read the answer and compare the answer with your code?